# Remove gaps between points in cloud - make them bigger as you get closer?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, webgl

When I view my point cloud from a distance, all the points seem to overlap, giving the impression of a continuous surface, which is the effect I'm trying to achieve. However, as I get closer to the cloud, you can see the individual point squares and the gaps between them. How can I get rid of these gaps? Make the point size bigger as the camera gets smaller for instance?

Here is a [working example](http://fieldviewer-niallssandpit.rhcloud.com/static/viewer/viewer.html). If you press the up arrow to zoom in, you eventually see individual points rather than the continuous "cloud"

By the way - there is a more verbose version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822763/in-browser-3d-animated-pointclouds-3d-pixels) if you want some more context.

Thanks

Niall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in [the particle vertex shader for my Cubes](https://github.com/kpreid/cubes/blob/4268459bbadd7ffb27d6cee235aba0aff2b89817/shaders/vertex_particle.glsl), probably in an unnecessarily verbose way.

```
// Compute pixel scale for points
vec4 testPosition = eyePosition;
testPosition.x = uPixelsPerClipUnit.x / uTileSize * 1.2/*appearance fudge factor*/;
testPosition.y = 0.0;
testPosition = uPMatrix * testPosition;
gl_PointSize = testPosition.x / testPosition.w * animationScale;
```

These are the variables you need to provide (the ones which start with `u` I had as uniforms):

- `eyePosition` is the location of the point in eye space (i.e. just before the projection matrix is applied, and after the model/view matrix/matrices are applied). The only part of it we actually care about is the `z` axis.
- `uPixelsPerClipUnit` is a `vec2` which is set up to be half the viewport pixel dimensions — it's just a conversion factor from −1-to-1 clip space scale to pixels.
- `uTileSize` and `animationScale` are just parameters specific to my game about how big the points should be. They don't need to be in two different places.
- `uPMatrix` is the projection matrix.

What we're actually doing here is getting the product of

- the eye-space-to-clip-space scale set by the projection matrix, at the z-depth of the point, and
- the clip-space-to-pixels scale

and using that to set the point size.

(I'd like to provide a self-contained working example, but I don't think I'll get around to it, so you get the snippet and half-baked explanation.)

Comment: amazing - thanks - I'll give that a go and let you know if I get it to work. I'm in at the deep end of WebGL here, so its nice to get some advice.

Comment: I don't understand where eyePosition comes from. Is it just one of the magic variables that threejs/webgl create for your convenience, or is it something you have passed to the shader? It doesn't seem to exist in my shader

Comment: I think `eyePosition` must be predefined in my version of three.js as `cameraPosition`. By the way, if anyone has a link to a definition of what exactly `modelMatrix`,`modelViewMatrix`,`projectionMatrix`,`viewMatrix`,`normalMatrix` are then that would make my life significantly more pleasant. Can find any info anywhere. Not sure why it seems to be such a secret!

Comment: <-- typo on the previous post: can't

Comment: @nrob The descriptions of the variables I mention are so you can set them up properly, not things that already exist anywhere. I'm not using Three.js so there's no common terminology.

Comment: Hi Kevin - have a green tick for answering my question.

It turns out from some extended googling, that what I'm ultimately trying to achieve is volume rendering.